# Handling state full requests in load balanced ecosystem

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing

I have a scenario where a web application is running on tomcat server and there is a load balancer that is managing multiple instances of tomcat sharing the same web application, suppose instances are Inst1, Inst2, Inst3.

There is also a lower level service which does the heavy load job which may take more than 30 minutes to process the request. Any request coming to the web application needs to be forwarded to this service and an ack mechanism is there to notify the web application when the heavy load job is complete.

Now User A requests the web application which then hits the Inst1 (Load balanced) ----> Lower level service ----> Ack goes back to any instance.

How will I notify back to the user A about the response who is still waiting on his machine.

Just as an additional information, I am using REST through out for Ack and other mechanisms.

My challenge is how this context is being maintained and how this communication will happen in above case. I am absolutely naive from load balancer concepts and have got some really basic concepts level understanding.

Thanks for help.

AJ

Comment: Will using sticky sessions with JSESSIONID appended to headers solve this problem?

Comment: Does not look like a network problem more like enterprise application problem. You just can't have a http response wait for 30 minutes. Use message queue internal and have requests ping the service if their job is done.